# How to make my server support SFTP?

Tags: ftp, sftp

Hello I have a FTP server and some service we are working with (they are supposed to upload every day some files to our server) said they are only supporting SFTP :

1.is it a migration ? do I need to change/install something in my server to make this work ?

2.What will heppend to my files when I will make thoses changes ?

3.I already had an answer telling that we may need more info about my server, can you please tell me how to get you this info ?

Thanks !

Comment: It depends on your operating system, which you did not specify.

Answer (score 1):

If the server is UNIX/Linux, you probably already have SSH installed.  SFTP is a component of SSH and so you should already have it as well.

If that's the case, then just use the sftp command on the client-side to transfer the files instead of ftp.

If the client is Windows, use a program such as WinSCP to do the transfers and within WinSCP, select the SFTP option.  I believe this is actually the default.

Since you have not provided the OS details of the server or client, it's hard for us to answer you.

Comment: thank you your answer helped me, i didnt know i already have sftp 'installed'

Answer (score -1):

There are two similar sounding protocols that have  similar names and both do secure  file transfer by replacing the clear text credential exchange and data transfer to an encrypted channel providing transport security.

Do you want SFTP ?
SSH File Transfer Protocol   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol

Or FTPS ?
That  is normal FTP with TLS encryption bolted on https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS

The first one is sufficiently different from normal FTP and uses different default ports that you can install it in addition to and without modifying your existing ftp service.

The second requires either extending or replacing the existing ftp service.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, I was talking about the first one SFTP do you know the process to go from FTP to SFTP please ?